# Проблема отправки почты с VDS на gmail.com

Tags: gmail

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброго времени. При отправке писем на gmail.com получаю в ответ ошибку

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

```
  логин@gmail.com
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4010:c0f::1a]:
    550-5.7.1 [2a02:f680:1:1101::fe] Our system has detected that this message does
    550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and
    550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review
    550-5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more
    550 5.7.1 information. pe3si14937587lbc.163 - gsmtp
```

немного почитав, вроде как понял что тут проблема с     PTR (реверсная запись)

ispmanager 5, debian 7

**я добавлял записи в Доменные имена (DNS):**

```
mail.sait.ru.  3600 PTR (реверсная запись) 194.xx.xxx.xx 
smtp.sait.ru.  3600 PTR (реверсная запись) 194.xx.xxx.xx 
sait.ru. 3600 PTR (реверсная запись) 194.xx.xxx.xx
```

перезагружал сервер.. НИЧЕГО.. Подскажите как можно решить проблему ? спасибо

Comment: Отправляете с IPv6, а в PTR у вас IPv4

Comment: Хотя у http://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx заявляется, что на IPv6 тоже висит PTR, так что остаётся спросить, действительно ли письма отправляются именно с домена make-board.ru без всяких поддоменов и прочего

Comment: я к сожалению не понял, что и как нужно сделать .. (( 
письма отпрвляются с одного домена , без поддоменов